# Path of android.R.id.empty drawable?

Tags: android, drawable

I am specifically looking for the drawable `android.R.id.empty`.

Does any one have an idea what the source path of that default Android drawable is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file where it is defined is located in

> YOUR_SKD_DIRECTORY/platforms/A_PLATFORM/data/res/values/ids.xml

It is not a drawable but an id as you can clearly see from *android.R.**id**.empty*.

This id is meant to be set on a `View` which should be displayed in case your `ListView` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I stumpled upon a really nice guide for Froyo drawables. And don't forget to use android.R.drawables for your integer id. http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/